# Regex to match perl variable

Tags: regex, perl, variables

I'm currently learning about regular expressions and I'm trying to create a regex to match any legal variable name in Perl.

**This is what I wrote so far:**

```
^\$[A-Za-z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

The only problem is the regex returns true for special signs, for example the string ***$a&*** will return true.

What I did wrong?

Thanks!
Rotem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `$` at the end, otherwise it's just matches as far as it can and ignores the rest. So it should be:

```
^\$[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9]*$
```

Comment: That will match a string which contains just a variable.  It will not match a string containing a variable.

Comment: Just to be sure, this regex will also do the same job - ^\$[A-Za-z_]\w*$ ?

Comment: It looks like that's what he wants. Otherwise, it would be correct for it to be true for `$a&`, since that's just a variable followed by the `&` operator. But notice that his regex begins with `^`, so he expects the variable to be at the beginning.

Comment: That will match the exact string `$foo` but it will not match the `$foo` part of `$foo = 42` making it not very useful.  If you're learning regexes, its important to learn how to make them grab pieces out of strings.

Comment: That fails to match `$17` and `$élite`, both of which are legal variable names in Perl.

Comment: I want the regex to check if a given name is a legal name for a variable. Legal such as: '$rotem', '$_color', '$eyes_num_1', and illegal for: '$1eye', '&rot'.. So the regex I wrote on the comment is also true or not?

Comment: @tchrist - As far as I know, variable name shouldn't start with a number. Isn't it right?

Comment: @Rotem `"foo" =~ /(o+)/; print $1; @12 = (1..10); print $12[7];`

Comment: And then there is `$foo::bar`, or `%::`.

Answer (score 8):

Parsing Perl is difficult, and the rules for what is and is not a variable are complicated.  If you're attempting to parse Perl, consider using [PPI](https://metacpan.org/module/PPI) instead.  It can parse a Perl program and do things like find all the variables.  PPI is what [perlcritic](https://metacpan.org/module/perlcritic) uses to do its job.

If you want to try and do it anyway, here's some edge cases to consider...

```
$^F
$/
${^ENCODING}
$1
$élite           # with utf8 on
${foo}
*{foo} = \42;
*{$name} = \42;  # with strict off
${$name} = 42;   # with strict off
```

And of course the other sigils `@%*`.  And detecting if something is inside a single quoted string.  Which is my way of strongly encouraging you to use PPI rather than try to do it yourself.

If you want practice, realistic practice is to pull the variable out of a larger string, rather than do exact matches.

```
# Match the various sigils.
my $sigils         = qr{ [\$\@\%*] }x;

# Match $1 and @1 and so on
my $digit_var      = qr{ $sigils \d+ }x;

# Match normal variables
my $named_var      = qr{ $sigils [\w^0-9] \w* }x;

# Combine all the various variable matches
my $match_variable = qr{ ( $named_var | $digit_var ) }x;
```

This uses the `()` capture operator to grab just the variable.  It also uses the `/x` modifier to make the regex easier to read and alternative delimiters to avoid [leaning toothpick syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome).  Using `\w` instead of `A-Z` ensures that Unicode characters will be picked up when [utf8](https://metacpan.org/module/utf8) is on, and that they won't when its off.  Finally, `qr` is used to build up the regex in pieces.  Filling in the gaps is left as an exercise.

Comment: I'm not intending to use my regex. I'm just learning how to write them and I thought about variable name as a good practice that's all :)
Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, didn't know this was just an exercise.  In that case, I've updated with a good start on how you'd tackle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to solve this problem to create a simple source code analyzer.
This subroutine extracts Perl user variables from an input section of code

```
sub extractVars {
    my $line = shift;
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/#.*//;       # Remove comments
    $line =~ s/\s*;\s*$//;  # Remove trailing ;
    my @vars = ();
    my $match = 'junk';
    while ($match ne '') {
        push @vars, $match if $match ne 'junk';
        $match = ''; 
        if ($line =~ s/(
                [\@\$\%]            # $@%
                {?                  # optional brace
                \$?                 # optional $
                [\w^0-9]            # begin var name
                [\w\-\>\${}\[\]'"]* # var name
                [\w}\]]             # end var name
                |
                [\@\$\%]            # $@%
                {?                  # optional brace
                \$?                 # optional $
                [\w^0-9]            # one letter var name
                [}\]]?              # optional brace or bracket
                )//x) {
            $match = $1;
            next;
        }
    }
    return @vars;
}
```

Test it with this code:

`my @variables = extractVars('$a $a{b} $a[c] $scalar @list %hash $list[0][1] $list[-1] $hash{foo}{bar} $aref->{foo} $href->{foo}->{bar} @$aref %$hash_ref %{$aref->{foo}} $hash{\'foo\'}  "$a" "$var{abc}"');`

It does NOT work if the variable name contains spaces, for example:

- `$hash{"baz qux"}`
- `${ $var->{foo} }[0]`